# Using Raster clipper in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, clip

I have several raster tiles that I have merged. I don't know why I get a black border around the merged map (the pixel values are 0).
I have created a polygon for the area of interest to remove the black area but the raster clipper seems not to work and again after the clip, I have the black border around my raster.
First I don't know why Qgis creates the black border and second I don't know why the Raster clipper doesn't work.

I know that I can remove the black border (just for visualization purposes) through *Property --> Transparency* tab. I am looking for a permanent solution.

Answer (score 1):

If the raster image and polygon layer have the same projection the clip should work properly. To remove the black border in No Data value, you can assign `-9999` in No Data value as you can see below:

[image]

Select `Mask layer` to select the polygon cutline that you want to use as clip layer, and select `Crop the extent of the target dataset to the extent of the cutline`